# router-outlet and routerLink works with ng serve, but not with ng build

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am new at angular 2 development and Im building an app using routing module.
when I'm running it with ng serve I can move between different components,
but when Im building it with "`ng build`" or "`ng build --prod`" I cant see the component that needs to be showen insted of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.
Can anyone help me figure that?

when I open the console in chrome I see the following message:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute
>   'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL
>   'file:///C:/Users/tc34677/Documents/GitHub/Emint-Zabad/dist/home'
>   cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL
>   'file:///C:/Users/tc34677/Documents/GitHub/Emint-Zabad/dist/index.html'.
>   Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state
>   object with URL
>   'file:///C:/Users/tc34677/Documents/GitHub/Emint-Zabad/dist/home'
>   cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL
>   'file:///C:/Users/tc34677/Documents/GitHub/Emint-Zabad/dist/index.html'.
>       at BrowserPlatformLocation.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.BrowserPlatformLocation.replaceState
>   (platform-browser.es5.js:1925)
>       at PathLocationStrategy.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.PathLocationStrategy.replaceState
>   (common.es5.js:640)
>       at Location.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.Location.replaceState
>   (common.es5.js:321)
>       at router.es5.js:4163
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (Observable.js:224)
>       at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError
>   (Subscriber.js:247)
>       at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:187)
>       at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next
>   (Subscriber.js:125)
>       at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:89)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
>   (map.js:83)
>       at BrowserPlatformLocation.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.BrowserPlatformLocation.replaceState
>   (platform-browser.es5.js:1925)
>       at PathLocationStrategy.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.PathLocationStrategy.replaceState
>   (common.es5.js:640)
>       at Location.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.Location.replaceState
>   (common.es5.js:321)
>       at router.es5.js:4163
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (Observable.js:224)
>       at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError
>   (Subscriber.js:247)
>       at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:187)
>       at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next
>   (Subscriber.js:125)
>       at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:89)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
>   (map.js:83)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:766)
>       at zone.js:844
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:424)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
>       at  defaultErrorLogger @ core.es5.js:1020

Comment: when you use `ng serve` a node based lite server is instantiated which serves your application, when you are using `ng build` it just compiles and produces dist folder with the output, It seems you are trying to just open the html page in browser with your absolute path `c:\...index.html`, if that is the case you need to host your application somewhere before running, may be on IIS or some other host, Hope this helps!!, Cheers!!

Comment: I too face this issue. Accessing the page from the hosted location, got this error in the browser console.
Edit: In case this detail may helps to diagnose.Using node as server. `ng build && node ./location/to/startfile`. This is what I have in the node startup script. And included the 'dist' folder as static, public folder in the node.